# swift - NSFetchRequest Order By Syntax

Tags: ios, swift

What's up guys.

I'm currently doing this:

```
var results = NSArray()
        let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Work")



        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Work", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        let monthDesc = entity.attributesByName["shortMonth"] as NSAttributeDescription!
        let keyPathExpression  = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "date")
        // Does not really matter
        let countExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [keyPathExpression])
        let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
        expressionDescription.name = "count"
        expressionDescription.expression = countExpression
        expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType


        fetch.propertiesToFetch = [monthDesc, expressionDescription]
        fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = [monthDesc]
        fetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
        //var error: NSError? = nil




        fetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;


        do {
            results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetch)

        } catch {
            print("Unable to fetch results")
            abort()
        }


        let months = results.flatMap{$0["shortMonth"] as? String}
        let countt = results.flatMap{$0["count"] as? Double}

        print("Months \(months)")
        print("Countt \(countt)")
```

This bring me back two arrays with the month name and the count of records for that month name.

Results:

```
Months ["Apr", "Feb", "Mar", "May"]
Countt [4.0, 10.0, 12.0, 5.0]
```

In this entity, I also have an attribute for monthNumber.

How would I be able to print out these arrays sorted by that month number?

It seems like it's doing alphabetical order right now.

Thank you

Comment: Group by and fetch by both `monthDesc` and `monthNumber`, sort by `monthNumber`, use `monthDesc` for display? Note that it would probably be a good idea to not store the month name in the data at all, but just do the conversion when displaying.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what was asked:

```
var results = NSArray()
        let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Work")



        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Work", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        let monthDesc = entity.attributesByName["shortMonth"] as NSAttributeDescription!
        let monthNumber = entity.attributesByName["month"] as NSAttributeDescription!
        let keyPathExpression  = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "date")
        let countExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [keyPathExpression])
        let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
        expressionDescription.name = "count"
        expressionDescription.expression = countExpression
        expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType

        fetch.propertiesToFetch = [monthDesc, monthNumber, expressionDescription]
        fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = [monthDesc, monthNumber]

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "month", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetch.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        fetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

        fetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

        do {
            results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetch)

        } catch {
            print("Unable to fetch results")
            abort()
        }


        let months = results.flatMap{$0["shortMonth"] as? String}
        let countt = results.flatMap{$0["count"] as? Double}

        print("Months \(months)")
        print("Countt \(countt)")
```

This will group by both the monthNumber and the monthName and will sort by monthNumber and outputting the monthName and count.

Output:

```
Months ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"]
Countt [3.0, 10.0, 3.0, 10.0]
```